# Copy code from AWS CodeCommit to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codecommit

I have a AWSCodeCommit repository where developers check-in the code. Now since, this is for a PoC, I don't want to create a CI-CD pipeline, instead I would like to copy the code from CodeCommit to my AWS EC2 instance. I would then run my code on EC2 instance to view the results. Does anyone know how to copy the code from CodeCommit to EC2 instance ?. I know using scp to copy code from my laptop to EC2, but since we collaborate on CodeCommit I think it would be nice to get the latest code from repository and then run it on the instance. Any help appreciated. Thanks

**Thank you and Regards,**

Santosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install `git`
- Configure with AWS credentials
- Do a `git clone` on the CodeCommit repository

This will provide a local copy of the code checked into the repository.

See: [Setting Up for AWS CodeCommit - AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up.html)